# Why I am getting one more character?

Tags: c#, mysql, blob

Hello Im using this C# code for images upload.

```
 protected void UploadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
    string contentType = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType;
    using (Stream fs = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream)
    {
        using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs))
        {
            byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
            using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr))
            {
                string query = "INSERT INTO foto(FileName, ContentType, Content) VALUES (@FileName, @ContentType, @Content)";
                using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query))
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileName", filename);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContentType", contentType);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Content", bytes);
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
}
```

I upload the image in a longblob field, then to show the image I am using C# WebService, AJAX, JavaScript, converting the image to Base64String but image is displayed like if do not exist.

Here is my Base64String:

[Base64String](http://pastebin.com/53q9fRv7)

As you can see the problem is with this extra characters:

```
AAEAAAD/////AQAAAAAAAAAPAQAAAHgBAAAC
```

Why this happen? And how can I solve it?

Comment: That is a binary format serialization header, which is odd.  Have you looked at the data in the table? Does it include those lead bytes?  If not you need to show the code that loads and reads the data prior to the ToBase64String call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you replace the bellowed lines with your above code

```
      protected void UploadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
        string contentType = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType;
        using (Stream fs = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream)
            {
            using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs))
                {
                System.Drawing.Image imagetuUpload = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(fs);

                Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(imagetuUpload);
                System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
                bitmap.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                stream.Position = 0;
                byte[] upproimag = new byte[stream.Length + 1];
                stream.Read(upproimag, 0, upproimag.Length);

                string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
                using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr))
                    {
                    string query = "INSERT INTO foto(FileName, ContentType, Content) VALUES (@FileName, @ContentType, @Content)";
                    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query))
                        {
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileName", filename);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContentType", contentType);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Content", upproimag);
                        con.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        con.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
        }
```

i hop it may help you :)

Comment: for view on C# asp.net page use below code     imguser.ImageUrl = "data:image/jpg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(SQL blob);

Comment: Was a problem calling the image! but thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

long time back i was in same issue i do not remember other than doing this at that time:

I check if I am wrong or not going here:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/hpP45/
```

I try to decode first(google bse64 decoder )

```
https://www.base64decode.org/
```

and save decoded binary data as an jpeg file and open it.

if it does not open then i guess,there might be issue on your base64 encoding